# Does Android Studio use appcompat v7 even if not required?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

After migrating from eclipse my APK size grew roughly by 1.5MB.
Checking in the .iml file I see: `<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="appcompat-v7-22.0.0" level="project" />`
I guess AS includes appcompat always. Even if not required by `build.gradle` script and not used in the app.

`R.java` also has tons of references to appcompat.

I repeat my `build.gradle` has no reference to appcompat:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}
```

Does anybody have this issue?

Comment: I don't really know why appcompat has been added (maybe as part of play-services?) but to reduce the application size, you can specifically reference only the libs you need in play-services as per https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup. Should shave off a few mbs if you don't need absolutely everything in play-services. I for instance, only needed the GCM and the ads. Do this and see if the (possibly indirect) dependency on appcompat disappears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Play Services version `com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0` or above now uses `appcompat-v7`, you have to use the previous version of play services:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'.
```

It's better described in this post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32096389/5135768

Answer (score 0):

Check your `build.gradle` in your module.

If the `dependencies` block contains

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:XX.X.X'
}
```

it means that your app is using AppCompat.

If you don't use it, remove this line from the build.gradle and sync the project.

Comment: There is no dependence on com.android.support:appcompat in build.gradle

Comment: run `gradle clean` and then rebuild the project

Comment: Did so, and there is still appcompat present. Strange.

Comment: It is very strange. Can you post your build.gradle and the content of your libs folder?

Comment: dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}

And there are no libs