# Attribute "titleTextStyle" has already been defined?

Tags: android

I have imported an eclipse android project into android studio 1.2.2
The gradle of my project:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':unifiedPreferenceLib')
    compile project(':viewPagerIndicatorLib')
    compile project(':slidingUpFourSquare')
    compile project(':stylishDialogLib')
    compile project(':swipeListViewLib')
    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':textDrawLib')
    compile project(':cardview')
    compile project(':editTextFormLibrary')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/CWAC-LocationPoller.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.8.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/ParseCrashReporting-1.8.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
    compile files('libs/blurnavdrawerlib.jar')
    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.1.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.15.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.15.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-jackson2-1.15.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/loremipsum-1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/splunk-mint-4.0.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/textdrawlib.jar')
}
```

I am getting

> Error:(1) Attribute "titleTextStyle" has already been defined

pointing to my colors.xml but my xml file does not even have this element with such an attribute.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem is `'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'`
defines the attribute `titleTextStyle` which is also defined in another library, thus the conflict rises.

Other people have had the same problem with Action Bar Sherlock after adding it([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733021/error-after-adding-dependencies-to-action-bar-sherlock-in-android-studio-0-5-8) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745803/gradle-error-attribute-xxx-has-already-been-defined-in-android-studio)) where appcompat-v7 already had an actionbar with the same functionality (same `titleTextStyle` attribute as well). Using ActionBar from appcompat-v7 over ActionBarSherlock was recommended.

In your case appcompat v7 isn't directly added as a dependency however

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30600744/4807777)

> The last version of Google Play Services now uses appcompat-v7, so u
>   can't use it with actionbarsherlock. You have to use only appcompat-v7
>   or the previous version of play services:
>
> ```
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
> ```

You were using the latest so the conflict appearead. You could, as suggested, use only appcompat or stick to actionbarsherlock and switch to playservices version 7.0.0.

Looking over [the android support library features](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html) i noticed they guide you to:

> In general, we recommend including the v4 support and v7 appcompat
>   libraries, because they support a wide range of Android versions and
>   provide APIs for recommended user interface patterns.

which is another indication as not to use actionbarsherlock.

Comment: I already solved this issue by removing actionBarSherlock library altogether. A particular library project which i have been using depended upon actionbarsherlock. I tweaked this library to compile without the need for actionbarsherlock. Anyway what you say seem the right way to go. So awarding you unless someone else has a better answer.

Comment: What if I do need to use 2 libraries that define attributes of specific views, using declare-styleable , yet even though the views have a different package, the attributes names are the same? How can I handle this?

Comment: @androiddeveloper this seems like a broad enough problem for many users to encounter thus deserving it's own question. This question alone has had numerous hits in the last 2 months. I suggest you post your question separately, I will answer when I get the time to, unless someone else provides a relevant answer before that. Cheers!

Comment: compiling 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0' solved the problem, thanks!