# Error: Attribute "titleTextStyle" has already been defined

Tags: android

After compile 'csipsimple' coding I use splash activity then this type problem occur. Any one know please suggest me.

[image: my problem]

Comment: Check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31769937/attribute-titletextstyle-has-already-been-defined

Comment: i have follow this link but it is not work properly in my project